# How should breadcrumbs be marked up? Are lists appropriate?

Tags: website-design, html, semantics

Trying to work out how best to mark up a breadcrumb area on my page and I'm not sure how I should contain it. In my mind there are three options:

#### Option 1 - Just Links

```
<nav>
    <a ...>Link 1</a>
    /
    <a ...>Link 2</a>
    / ...
</nav>
```

#### Option 2 - An Ordered List

```
<nav>
    <ol>
        <li>
            <a ...>Link 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            ...
        </li>
        ...
    </ol>
</nav>
```

#### Option 3 - An Unordered List

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a ...>Link 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            ...
        </li>
        ...
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Which would be the best to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [this source](https://www.permeance.com.au/web/terry.mueller/home/-/blogs/how-to-make-navigation-bars-and-breadcrumbs-accessible) suggests, this is the recommended markup:

```
<map title="Breadcrumbs">
    <a href="/">Home</a> 
    > <a href="/foo">Foo</a> 
    > <a href="/bar">Bar</a> 
</map>
```

The links are part of the [G65](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/G65.html), which states:

> Breadcrumb trails are implemented using links to the Web pages...

The `<map>` tag is from [H50](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/NOTE-WCAG20-TECHS-20081211/H50).

Yet, you may wish to consider what seems to be a more popular markup, using `<nav>` instead of `<map>`:

```
<nav title="Breadcrumbs">
    <a href="/">Home</a> 
    > <a href="/foo">Foo</a> 
    > <a href="/bar">Bar</a> 
</nav>
```

Breadcrumbs are definitely not lists (ordered or not) since they are just a path within an hierarchy. A list involves siblings, which are not part of breadcrumbs.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure about using the `<map>` element, this seems to go against the HTML5 specification: "The `map` element, in conjunction with an `img` element and any area element descendants, defines an image map. The element represents its children." The HTML4.01 specification is different in that it states "... image map (or other navigation mechanism)".

Comment: I can't really challenge that (despite H50). From what I've seen `<nav>` is much more popular. I'll amend my answer.

Comment: [microformats.org](http://microformats.org/wiki/breadcrumbs-formats) additionally suggests using `role="navigation" aria-label="breadcrumbs"` on the container, but I've seen recommendations along the lines of "don't `role` it if the tag already has that meaning", too.